Как убрать libgfortran из C++?
Без этой библиотеки исполняемый файл не запускается. А она много весит. Как избавиться от этой зависимости?

очевидно же: не использовать библиотечные функции, реализованные на фортране. это чуть менее чем все «тяжёлые» вычисления, например.

Какую-то кривую версию mingw поставили? Вот нормальная: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075
